# The DNS server isn't responding

Tags: networking, dns

My wireless laptop is having issues connecting to the internet. The laptop is connected to the router but has no internet, when I've run the troubleshooting software, I get the response "The DNS server isn't responding". I have tried the options given below, but none have worked. I also have a second laptop and a phone both of which are able to connect to the internet using the same router without any issue. The laptop which is having issues can ping 8.8.8.8, but it gets no response when trying to ping google.com. Any tips would be great.

- Specifying DNS address (8.8.8.8 alternative 8.8.4.4)
- Resetting DNS settings
- Network reset
- Router reset
- Disabling miniport adapters in device manager
- Starting in safe mode with networking
- Starting in safe mode without networking
- System restore (3 different dates, system restore failed each time even in safe mode)
- Using the following commands:
- ipconfig/flushdns
- ipconfig/registerdns
- ipconfig/release
- ipconfig/renew
- netsh int ip reset
- netsh winsock reset

Thanks

Comment: Is your network tagged as Public or Private (preferably)?  Have you tried temporarily disabling your Windows firewall or Internet security software?  If you have any VPN software installed on your laptop, try disabling it. Is IPv6 in-use?  Are you certain your netmask is correct?  If you're using DHCP, is your DHCP scope full?  Besides Google Public DNS, here's a few others to try: OpenDNS [208.67.222.222 / 208.67.220.220] and Comodo SecureDNS [156.154.70.22 / 156.154.71.22].  When in doubt, try your ISP's DNS servers.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I've given these a try, but still no luck. Cheers.